# How do I find my store_id for use with the Uber eats api

Tags: uber-api

I’m trying to display my stores menu on my website using the UberEats API

GET v2/eats/stores/{store_id}/menus

I can’t find my store_id

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your stores Id with this request:

> ```
> curl -X GET -H \
> "authorization: Bearer $UBER_TOKEN" \
> 'https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/stores?limit=10'
> ```

More info: https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v1/get-eats-stores